# How to customize the default download location for Paclets

Tags: paclets

Whenever Mathematica downloads resource data from its server it automatically gets stored in the C: drive of my Windows computer. Is there a way I can control and customize the default download location. I am fast starting to run out of space on my C: drive because of these downloads.
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this one.

1. Close all instances of Mathematica if running.
2. Create a new environment variable called MATHEMATICA_USERBASE.
3. Point the variable to the location you want Mathematica to store the downloaded resources.
4. Restart Mathematica. It should now automatically use the new location.